# MySQL PHP query return specified result and not all the rows needed

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 main tables to get data about medications.

The first table is the medication list `t3`:

[image]

`t3` contains a medication ID with it's name. Other info are not eligible for now.

**PLEASE concentrate on the `med_id = 16`** for now.

The table med_pharmacy `t1` is where if a medication exist in our stock, will appear in it. Currently I have 2 stocks of the `med_id = 16` in it only:

[image]

The third table consultation_med `t2` is where I can collect data about how much is given from that medication, but here, the `t1.med_pharmacy_id` is the FK in it:

[image]

Now, in my PHP page I have the following table:

```
      <tr class="bg-info" id="after_tr">
          <th>Med ID</th>
          <th>Med Name</th>
          <th>Med Expiry</th>
          <th>Barcode</th>
          <th>received</th>
          <th>Pills received</th>
          <th>Date Received</th>
          <th>Pills distributed</th>
          <th>Still (in tablets)</th>
          <th>Still (in pills)</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach($fetchRes as $res) { ?>
        <tr id="<?php echo $res['med_id'] ?>">
          <td><?php echo $res['med_id'] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $res['med_name'] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $res['med_expiry'] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $res['med_barcode'] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $res['med_tablet'] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $res['med_pill'] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $res['med_received'] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $res['given_pills'] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo floor($res['still_tablets'])?> (Exact:<?php echo number_format($res['still_tablets'], 2) ?>)</td>
          <td><?php echo $res['still_pills'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
```

Which is working well, but instead of showing the the second tablet of the med_id=16 have `still_pills = 100` and where no pills is given to anyone from this tablet that have different barcode. It only shows the list of medications that have been used and given to patients:

[image]

**HERE IS THE QUERY I AM USING**

```
$clinic_id = $_SESSION['clinic_id'];
$getRes = "SELECT t1.med_id, t1.med_pharmacy_id,
t3.med_name,
t1.med_expiry, 
t1.med_barcode, 
t1.med_tablet, 
t1.med_pill, 
t1.med_received,
sum(t2.given_quantity) as given_pills,
t1.med_tablet - ((sum(t2.given_quantity)*t1.med_tablet)/t1.med_pill) as still_tablets,
(t1.med_pill-sum(t2.given_quantity)) as still_pills
FROM med_pharmacy t1, consultation_med t2, medication t3 WHERE t1.med_pharmacy_id = t2.med_pharmacy_id AND t1.med_id=t3.med_id
AND t1.clinic_id=:cid GROUP BY t1.med_pharmacy_id, t1.med_expiry,t1.med_barcode,t1.med_tablet,t1.med_pill,t1.med_received";
$execGetRes = $conn->prepare($getRes);
$execGetRes->bindValue(':cid', $clinic_id);
$execGetRes->execute();
```

Comment: This looks very like your other question. ?!? If it's genuinely exploring some other aspect of the problem, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are selecting from the 3 tables at the same time, this will prevent you from seeing the medication if it has not been given at least once... Instead, select all the stocks from the clinic, and join the transactions.

```
SELECT t1.med_id, t1.med_pharmacy_id,
t3.med_name,
t1.med_expiry, 
t1.med_barcode, 
t1.med_tablet, 
t1.med_pill, 
t1.med_received,
sum(t2.given_quantity) as given_pills,
t1.med_tablet - ((ifnull(sum(t2.given_quantity),0)*t1.med_tablet)/t1.med_pill) as still_tablets,
(t1.med_pill-sum(t2.given_quantity)) as still_pills
FROM med_pharmacy t1
LEFT JOIN consultation_med t2 USING (med_pharmacy_id,clinic_id)
LEFT JOIN medication t3 USING (med_id,clinic_id)
WHERE t1.clinic_id=:cid GROUP BY t1.med_pharmacy_id, t1.med_expiry,t1.med_barcode,t1.med_tablet,t1.med_pill,t1.med_received
```

I am not 100% on this, but this should help... what we do is select all from T1 according to clinic_id. Then, we join data from other tables if it exists.

To better explain the query, I have first taken out the 2 extra tables from the main query. Which would leave us with just the initial stocks for our clinic. Using the `LEFT JOIN` is the proper way to "add extra information" to the main query. That means that even if there is no information in the other tables, the related row will not be ignored, it will just have `NULL` in the corresponding fields (this is why I added a `IFNULL` statement, to mean 0 instead). The `LEFT JOIN` needs 2 primary information, the table that should be joined and how to determine which row.

Here we are using the `USING` keyword for the join. This is useful as the two tables share the same column names. This typically tells MySQL to join rows from the second table according to the value of those columns. If the tables do not share column names, or the operation required is not a pure equals, we can use `ON` instead. After this, we should simply write the condition as we would do in the WHERE clause.

I suggest you read more on JOINS in your favorite database manual.

Comment: I got this error `Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.med_pharmacy_id,clinic_id) LEFT JOIN medication t3 USING (t1.med_pharmacy_id,c' at line 12 in C:\wamp64\www\ncd\php\getMedStat.php on line 23`

Comment: You cetainly copy pasted wrong, there is no '.' in my code at that place. You are not using the same query as I suggested, why did you add 't1.'?

Comment: because the first error was that there is no column called med_pharmacy_id

Comment: My mistake... I certainly mixed the tables since you wrote the third in the first place :) Try this edit?

Comment: Now it works properly. Now can you edit your answer and explaining the query because there is some new stuff there for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT t1.med_id, t1.med_pharmacy_id,
t3.med_name,
t1.med_expiry, 
t1.med_barcode, 
t1.med_tablet, 
t1.med_pill, 
t1.med_received,
sum(t2.given_quantity) as given_pills,
t1.med_tablet - ((sum(t2.given_quantity)*t1.med_tablet)/t1.med_pill) as still_tablets,
(t1.med_pill-sum(t2.given_quantity)) as still_pills
FROM med_pharmacy t1, consultation_med t2, medication t3 WHERE t1.med_pharmacy_id = t2.med_pharmacy_id AND t1.med_id=t3.med_id
AND t1.clinic_id=:cid GROUP BY t1.med_pharmacy_id, t1.med_expiry,t1.med_barcode,t1.med_tablet,t1.med_pill,t1.med_received limit 1";
```

Comment: I think because if there is no row in table 2, he can't do the sum right ?